# Unable to see button in MainActivity when coming back from another activity

Tags: java, android

I have a MainActivity where I am showing a button at the bottom of the screen and there some other buttons in the middle of the screen. 
At this point of time the bottom button is not doing any thing.
Clicking on any other buttons opens another activity - DisplayActivity.
My issue is that when I am coming back to MainActivity  from DisplayActivity, the bottom button is not getting displayed.
I have to kill the app and launch it again in order to see it.

Please let me know if you are aware of this issue and have any solution.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Post your activity code that holds these buttons

Comment: Post your both activity code here.

Comment: Post your code - how are gonna help you without that? Where do you instantiate your XML layout?

Comment: Ok, I'll post the code after few hours as not having access to it right now. But just wanted to know what could be the possible reason as I am simply coming back to MainActivity by hitting back button of my Android phone.

Comment: Is you button hidden by default?? I mean in your xml...

Comment: No..it is visible when the app is launched first.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you don't instantiate your layout XML in your onCreate method, but somewhere else